Prevent a capture app from getting muted on Windows mixer
I am having one issue with Bandicam on Windows 11. I have selected the audio recording source as the default sound card from Realtek HD audio. Everything works fine, and the video recording can be done with the audio from the sound card.  However, when I turn down the main volume of Windows, till the mute level, the audio input of Bandicam also gets muted. This causes the video recording to record without the audio.
Therefore, I need a way to prevent the audio input level of bandicam from getting muted on the Windows volume mixer.
I have attached the screenshots.
Bandicam settings
Windows Mixer

Don’t choose the speakers then mute the speakers but it looks like you can press on the icon. I haven’t used Bandicam in over a decade and stopped because of its quirks.
